# Python - Counting elements with specific key in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like:

```
list = [{'name':'Mike', 'sex':'m'}, {'name':'Rose', 'sex':'f'}]
```

And I need to count how many dictionaries with `sex = f` are in the list. I've tried something like:

```
count = (p['sex'] == 'f' for p in list)
```

but count returns as `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x1068831e0>` which I don't know what is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counts are not done implicitly, you have to work that out explicitly by for example using the builtin `sum`:

```
count = sum(p['sex'] == 'f' for p in list)
```

You can read up on generator expression from the docs:

[Generator expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)